# добавить дату к url

Tags: php, wordpress, json, api, get

на wordpress пытаюсь по api получить календарь.

```
$date=date("Y/m/d");
$response = wp_remote_get('http://api.calendar.drevle.com/2020/07/10');
$jsonString = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );
 
$cart = json_decode( $jsonString );
echo $date . "<br>";
echo $cart->day->gregorianDate . "<br>";
echo $cart->day->dayOfWeek . "<br>";
echo $cart->day->julianDate . "<br>";
echo $cart->day->tone . "<br>";
echo $cart->day->saints . "<br>";
echo $cart->day->fast . "<br>";
echo $cart->day->bows . "<p>";
echo $cart->day->dailyFeast . "<br>";
```

как в url вместо  http://api.calendar.drevle.com/2020/07/10 подставить [http://api.calendar.drevle.com/+сегодняшняя](http://api.calendar.drevle.com/+%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%88%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%8F) дата?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно так

```
$response = wp_remote_get('https://api.calendar.drevle.com/' . $date . '');
```

Comment: Спасибо Иван, Ваше решение помогло.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @Алексей если ответ помог нужно отметить его решённым.